# Objective C set ownership to file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to change files permissions and files ownership(root o mobile)
I already found out how to set permissions(777) successfully.
But now I am trying to get the files ownership.

Here is what I already got, but it does not seem to work:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
    [dict2 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mobile"] forKey:NSFileOwnerAccountName]; 
    [dict2 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mobile"] forKey:NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName];
    NSFileManager *fm2 = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    NSError *error2; 
    [fm2 setAttributes:dict2 ofItemAtPath:omgPath error:&error2];
```

Can someone help me with this? :)

Here is the working code for permissions:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:511] forKey:NSFilePosixPermissions]; 
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    NSError *error1; 
    [fm setAttributes:dict ofItemAtPath:omgPath error:&error1];
```

Here is another big Problem:

Without file permissions(if the file does not have permissions) I can't use the chown command otherwise I would use this.
If the ownership for the "owner" is root, I can't run the permissions script. so I have to get one working without the requirement to the other.

so setting ownership does not work without permissions
setting permissions only work if ownership is mobile, not root

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `stringWithFormat:` but not formatting anything into the string? The format string is itself a string, so if you just want that string unmodified, you can just use it by itself; you don't need to wrap every string in `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code segmentation faults for some reason, I'm not sure of the exact error but your style is a bit weird, e.g. why did you create a mutable dict instead of a normal one? And Why did you use NSStringWithFormat when you just needed a normal string? Anyway, I'm not sure which exact problem led to the seg fault but here it is fixed:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"mobile",NSFileOwnerAccountName,
                          @"mobile",NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName,
                          nil];

NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:dict ofItemAtPath:omgPath error:&error];
if(error){
    NSLog(@"Error settings permission %@",[error description]);
}
```

Comment: Don't determine if there was an error by checking if `error` is non-`nil`. Check the return value of the method. Only use the `error` object if that indicates failure.

Answer (score 0):

Only the superuser can set the ownership of a file. And, in general, you shouldn't use Cocoa from a privileged helper tool if the task can be done using a lower-level API, because that reduces the attack exposure.

You should check the error object that's returned by reference if the method fails (which unlike indiekiduk's answer, you should determine by looking at the boolean return value of the method, not whether or not the error variable is `nil`). It will explain why it failed.